# Unselectable Part of ListItem inListView inside Dialog

Tags: android, android-listview

I am experiencing something weird. I have a listview, and adapter, see below image.
[image]

When I click the item, see image below.
[image]

I am expecting that when I click the right part of the listview, something will happen, [my function for onitemclicklistener will be called], but unfortunately, it does not. This is weird. Is it because I am putting the listview inside the Dialog? 
Below is my dialog's layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my layout for each item,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSelect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution. I think, it solve your problem

Change listview  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and also in LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listSelect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </ListView>
```

Comment: if it is work then accept this answer and upvote then it help other person too.